# archlinux chroot updating pacman fails

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

*note: I am inside an Ubuntu installation chrooting into an Arch install*

When running `pacman -Syu` responds with

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from archlinux.polymorf.fr : Could not resolve host: archlinux.polymorf.fr
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.js-webcoding.de : Could not resolve host: mirror.js-webcoding.de
...
error: failed retrieving file 'community.db' from mirror.kavalinux.com : Could not resolve host: mirror.kavalinux.com
error: failed retrieving file 'community.db' from f.archlinuxvn.org : Could not resolve host: f.archlinuxvn.org
error: failed to update community (download library error)
error: failed to synchronize any databases
error: failed to init transaction (download library error)
```

see total [output](http://pastebin.com/MxiwuiYe)

Hopefully the output should suffice.

I had just installed archlinux, but unable to run grub-mkconfig due to the binary not existing in the Arch install.

Thus wanting to install grub (via chroot) to make arch bootable (running `os-probe` inside ubuntu does not detect the arch install) has its own issues.

**I am not able to update my pacman repository database**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the `/etc/resolv.conf` file to your chrooted session and replace the `nameserver` lines with the following lines:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save and restart the network.

Comment: You are a genius :p. I am use to these being setup for me by an Ubuntu install, thank you for informing me about this. Is there any configs(or tips) that are accepted as a "given" in Ubuntu install that need to be configured in Arch?

Comment: @Cybex , Welcome , just ask ,  there are a lot of experts here , you will get an answer from anyone .

Comment: I do have a new question :p http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312262/pacman-isntalling-a-package-invalid-mountpoints-etc-mtab