# Pacman error: could not open file: /etc/mtab: No such file or directory

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am having trouble with installing packages with pacman

Firstly updating pacman with `pacman -Syu` updates correctly with no issues,

however when attempting to install `sudo` with `pacman -S sudo` responds with:

```
[root@cx-W55xEU /]# pacman -S sudo             
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) sudo-1.8.17.p1-1

Total Download Size:   0.90 MiB
Total Installed Size:  3.73 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
error: could not open file: /etc/mtab: No such file or directory
error: could not determine filesystem mount points
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

After reading up about this, I attempted to install the package `filesystem` with `pacman -S filesystem` which should solve the `mtab` issue.

```
[root@cx-W55xEU /]# pacman -S filesystem
warning: filesystem-2015.09-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) filesystem-2015.09-1

Total Installed Size:  0.01 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                             [####################################################] 100%
error: GPGME error: Invalid crypto engine
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                           [####################################################] 100%
error: GPGME error: Invalid crypto engine
error: filesystem: missing required signature
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/filesystem-2015.09-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

After deleting, I reattempted to download the latest release and install that by `pacman -S filesystem` again:

```
[root@cx-W55xEU /]# pacman -S filesystem
warning: filesystem-2015.09-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) filesystem-2015.09-1

Total Download Size:   0.01 MiB
Total Installed Size:  0.01 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
error: could not open file: /etc/mtab: No such file or directory
error: could not determine filesystem mount points
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

My `/etc/mtab` file is clean i.e. no contents

I came across an arch wiki page about [mounts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mount) but not sure if I should create a symbolic link as specified to solve this issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `filesystem` is in the `base` group: why are you attempting to install it separately? Are you in the install chroot?

Comment: I solved it running `sudo ln -sf /proc/self/mounts /etc/mtab`